# Какой лимит скорости записи в syslog

Tags: php, highload, rsyslog

Собираюсь строить систему мониторинга ошибок на основе сислога => ELK. Пишу ошибки из PHP в сислог:

```
syslog(LOG_ERR, "мое отформатированное сообщение об ошибке");
```

В каком-то выступлении слышал, что люди писали в сислог какие-то громадные объемы сообщений. И в какой-то момент у них приложение/сервер начал сильно тормозить. Они заглянули в сорцы rsyslog и увидели, что тормоз - запись в файл, это синхронная операция, хотя сам демон работает асинхронно по UDP.

Какой примерный порядок лимита по скорости записи в сислог, например xxx запросов/сек? Как может сказаться на системе мониторинга ошибок? Пробовал достичь лимита, но не смог.

Comment: Если вы собираетесь перенаправлять сислог в ELK, то запись в файл rsyslog-ом какбы не нужна, так?

Comment: Так. Но файл будет использоваться. У нас еще проблемы с сетью, так что файл будет. Иначе ошибки "ошибка: обновление данных: нет сети" никуда не упадут. Хотя это наводит на мысль писать emergency в файл, остальное по сети

Comment: У меня нет приблизительного значения некоего "максимума скорости записи", потому что, понятно - это зависит от многих индивидуальных особенностей, скажем так, дисковой подсистемы сервера и т.д. и т.п. В качестве примера могу лишь сказать, что на моем сервере сейчас rsyslog пишет ~1000 строк логов в секунду от сквида + от циски в свой файл около 200 строк в секунду. Объемы, конечно, не громадные, и сервер не ложится. В будущем еще будут логи апача, но судя по текущей нагрузке - никаких оверхедов по записи в файл(ы) пока не предвидится.